# ant-junit 1.5.3 jar is not available

Tags: java, ant, junit, ant-junit

I'm working on very old system, we have ant 1.5.3 running and we need to add unit tests to the environment. As far as i have researched, there is no available ant-junit 1.5.3 jar version. did it had a different name before ant-junit-1.7.0? My application says that JUnitTask is not available when compiling. (because ant and ant-junit.jar should be of same version)

Comment: Versions from 1.6 onwards are available here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ant/ant-junit

Answer (score 0):

for `Ant 1.5.x` the classes for optional tasks, such as `<junit>` were contained in `optional.jar`, in the following directory: `org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit` to be precise.

from `Ant 1.6.x` onwards, `optional.jar` was split into multiple jars, one of them being `ant-junit-1.6.*.jar`.

so, i doubt `ant-junit-1.5.3.jar` ever existed.

read [**delegating-classloader-1.6**](http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#delegating-classloader-1.6), for more of this.